# Arduino if else code

Tags: c

I have made this If-Then-Else code, but it doesn't work.

First I tough only the analog code is wrong, but if I take a digital port, the code doesn't work either.

What did I do wrong?

```
int sensorPin = A0;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int sensorValue = 0.00001;  // variable to

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);  //LED BORD UIT
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);  //LED4
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);  //LED3
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);  //LED2
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);   //LED1
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);   //Elektro Magneet
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (A0 == HIGH) {
     digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
     digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   //LED on, magnet off
     digitalWrite(11, HIGH);   
     digitalWrite(10, HIGH);   
     digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(8, LOW);     

  } else {    
     digitalWrite(13, LOW); 
     digitalWrite(12, LOW);   // LED Off, magnet on
     digitalWrite(11, LOW);   
     digitalWrite(10, LOW);   
     digitalWrite(9, LOW);      
     digitalWrite(8, HIGH);     
  }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Be careful with that electro magnet. Those tend to use quite a bit of current, while the digital pins of the arduino can only source a maximum of 40mA. You don't want to "blow up" you Arduino.

Comment: To add to what @Gerben said, you'll want to keep current around and under 20mA on any I/O pin and under 100mA on the MCU. Beyond lighting a few LEDs, you'll have to use transistors, darlingtons and relays.

Answer (score 9):

Replace the line:

```
  if (A0 == HIGH) {
```

by this one:

```
  if (digitalRead(A0) == HIGH) {
```

If you plan on using the pin back as an analog input, use something like this:

```
  if (analogRead(A0) > 512) {
```

The explanation is what Ignacio said: you were comparing the pin "name" `A0` directly to `HIGH` instead of reading from the input named `A0`. To make it clearer, the two lines are equivalent:

```
if (A0 == HIGH)
if (0 == HIGH)
```

Get it?

There's more about what pin names to use with digitalRead() and analogRead() here:

- [analogRead(0) or analogRead(A0) at EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67087/analogread0-or-analogreada0).

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing the pin variable value with `HIGH`. If you want to get the value *at a digital input* then you need to use [`digitalRead()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/digitalRead).

Answer (score 2):

You have defined your pin as

```
int sensorPin = A0;
```

Which should be replaced with

```
#define sensorPin = A0
```

And then in your code, you need to read the value from  the pin in your `if` statement:

```
 if (digitalRead(sensorPin) == HIGH) {
```